# Why subtracting 1 is considered ill-conditioned?

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, condition-number

I was reading the [following](https://www.math.utk.edu/%7Eccollins/M577/Handouts/cond_stab.pdf) to better understand stability:

> Consider evaluating $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x}-1$ for $x$ near $0$. $C_f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}$ so $C_f(0) = 1$ so it is not
> ill-conditioned. To compute this we would have the 3 steps: $(1)\ t_1
>  = 1+x$, $(2)\ t_2 = \sqrt{t_1}$, and $f(x)=t_2-1$. Steps $(1)$ and $(2)$ are well-conditioned (condition numbers $0$ and $1/2$) while
> step $(3)$ is ill-conditioned. Thus we would say the algorithm is
> unstable.

I'm trying to understand why exactly the third step is ill-conditioned. Is it due to catastrophic cancellation because $t_1$ would be close to $1$? Is $1+x$ and $\sqrt{t_1}$ just not sensitive to perturbations due to floating point errors but $t_2-1$ is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subtract two nearly equal floating point numbers you lose precision.  In your example suppose we are working with seven place base $10$ numbers and let $x=10^{-4}$.  Then $t_1=1+x=1.000100$ is exact.  $t_2=\sqrt {t_1}=1.000050$ is within $\frac 12LSB$.  But when we subtract $t_2-1$ we get $5.0 \cdot 10^{-5}$ and only those two places are good.  The leading five places canceled out.  That is the catastrophic loss of precision.

Comment: So the catastrophic cancellation is the ill-conditioning that they're referring to here?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The error in the two numbers you are subtracting is less than $\frac 12LSB$, but the error in the difference is $10^5 LSB$ because the $LSB$ is much smaller due to the cancellation.

Comment: A point regarding your choice of words. Precision is the accuracy of the basic arithmetic operations. You do not lose precision in the subtraction, you lose accuracy. The two terms are not equivalent. Example: Accuracy is not limited by precision as higher accuracy can be achieved by carefully tracking the rounding errors. Not distinguishing between precision and accuracy can cause problems down the road.