# Finding roots of the equation $x^2−40x+1=0$

Tags: approximation, error-propagation, rounding-error, significant-figures

**The problem:** Given the equation $x^2−40x+1=0$, find its roots to five significant digits. Use $√399≐19.975$, correctly rounded to five digits.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

**My thoughts**:
[Solution part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsJqo.jpg)
[Solution part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRlZ7.jpg)
I am stuck after this.

Comment: Do show your efforts.

Comment: Sure sir, for 5 significant digits, relative error should be less than 0.0005%, so I calculated the roots using the given value of root(399) but after that I am clueless as of how to proceed further

Comment: should i use the true value of root(399) to find the true roots and then use the given value of root(399) in the question to find the approximate root to calculate the relative error,

Comment: @DilipKumarJena Please show your thoughts or at least how would you start.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova yes ma'am I uploaded the answer up to which i was able to solve. but I am unable to get the 2nd root with 5 significant digits accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with **ill-conditioning**, whereby the process of computation causes a loss of precision between inputs and outputs. Ill-conditioning takes various forms, but in the simplest version you subtract numbers that are nearly equal to each other and the result is less precise than the input. Digits that were significant in the inputs become leading zeroes in the difference, and lose their significance. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3337660/why-subtracting-1-is-considered-ill-conditioned) for more details.

Here, the roots are algebraically $20\pm\sqrt{399}$ and if we are given $\sqrt{399}\approx19.975$ we then compute

$20.000+19.975=39.975$

$\color{red}{20.0}00-\color{red}{19.9}75=\color{red}{00.0}25$

We have lost three significant digits for the smaller root and fail to get a precise rendering of the smaller root.

To beat the ill-conditioning, we render the root differently, using a form that's equivalent algebraically, but does not translate into an equivalent floating-point representation because it uses a different set of arithmetic operations. In plain English, with a difference involving square roots we may render

$a-b=(a^2-b^2)/(a+b)$

$20-\sqrt{399}=\dfrac{400-399}{20+\sqrt{399}}$

$=1/(20+\sqrt{399})$

and then use the well-conditioned sum for $20+\sqrt{399}$ to get the smaller root with the required full precision:

$1/(20+\sqrt{399})=1/39.975=\color{blue}{0.025016}.$

A check with a calculator shows that this is the correct floating five-digit representation of the smaller root.

**Martial arts**

I am not a martial artist, but I do know that a major objective of this discipline is to turn your opponent's strength to your advantage. Here, having identified an alternative expression for the smaller root, we note that since we know the two roots $20\pm\sqrt{399}$ add up to $40$ we may refine the larger root from $39.975$ to

$40-0.025016=39.974984$

(provided we can store the additional digits). Thus we have turned the original ill-conditioning around to *gain* precision in the larger root. This is, by another name, a convergent fixed-point iteration towards the true pair of roots.

Comment: Sir, Thank you for the clarification. I still have a major doubt on one basic concept, someone told me that relative error is used to find significant digits in True value. So, according to that the answer to this question would be 39.97498 and 0.02501 as the roots of the equation up to 5 significant digits?

Comment: In my second part I am actually adding _more_ significant digits to the original five in the larger root. The idea is once you have refined the conditioning you can use the refinement to add more precision to your initial estimates -- and the worse the conditioning was to start, the greater is the potential for such refinement.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you sir.